# When we talk about the helicity of a particle, why are we (apparently) ruling out the cases of the spin being perpendicular to the motion direction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin, chirality, helicity

[image]

If I assume the (linear) momentum is in the direction of the X-axis, could I NOT find the spin-up in the positive Y-(or Z-) axis and the spin-down in the negative Y-(or Z-) axis?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics)): “In physics, helicity is the projection of the spin onto the direction of momentum.” A massive particle can have zero helicity.

Comment: @Ghoster, is there any term for the condition of the spin being perpendicular to the momentum (making zero projection to the momentum direction), like none-handed or neutral-handed?

Comment: @MinnHtutkyaw in a particles rest frame it's helicity is certainly zero. This isn't really all that special though.

Comment: *is there any term…* “zero helicity”

Comment: Thank you, guys.